# Update text in HTML element without deleting other elements (with jQuery only)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

*How?*
**I know that there are solutions**, but I'm wondering if jQuery provides a **jQuery only solution without native Javascript functions** to do the following.

*What?*
Let's assume we have the following HTML and we want to change the text of the div with the class "testDiv". I know that this is bad HTML as there is an HTML tag together with pure text in another HTML tag.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.testDiv')[0].childNodes[1].nodeValue = "1"
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.testDiv')[0].childNodes[1].data = '2'
}, 900);

setTimeout(function() {
  var $el = $('.testDiv'),
    $preStuff = $el.find('span').clone(true);
  $el.text('3').prepend($preStuff);

}, 1300);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testDiv"><span>I like it </span> Hello World </div>
```

Do you find a way without native Javascript functions?

Am I right that this cannot be done by using jQuery functions only as it is a node? jQuery does not have a built in function for that right?

Comment: No, jQuery doesn't have anything built in to do this.

Comment: jQuery is a library for javascript.  It all uses native javascript under the hoods.  I'm not sure what you are asking.

Comment: Why don't you wrap the text in span, give it "id" or "class", and then do it in vanilla/jquery?

Comment: Why not `$(".testDiv").html($(".testDiv span").clone().html() + " text");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery has no methods specifically for isolating text nodes but once isolated you can wrap them in `$()` and use methods like `replaceWith()` or `wrap()` and turn them into tag elements and use methods like `text()` on the replacement

```js
var $el =  $('.testDiv').contents().last().wrap('<span>').parent()

setTimeout(function() {
 $el.text('1')
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  $el.text('2')
}, 900);

setTimeout(function() {      
  $el.text('3');
}, 1300);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testDiv"><span>I like it </span> Hello World </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `first()` in the place of the `[0]` and use `contents()` to get all the children, including text nodes.  However, I'm unaware of a jQuery method that would perform the `.data = <new value>` operation, so if that does not exist, you can use `get()` to get the textNode to change.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.testDiv').first().contents().get(1).data = "1";
}, 500);
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.testDiv').first().contents().get(1).data = "2";
}, 900);

setTimeout(function() {
  var $el = $('.testDiv'),
    $preStuff = $el.find('span').clone(true);
  $el.text('3').prepend($preStuff);

}, 1300);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="testDiv"><span>I like it </span> Hello World </div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can change the html in that div with the following code:

$('.testDiv').html('new text inside div');

Comment: How does this target the text node and answer the question?

Comment: The question is 'how can you change the html in the div with only jquery'. This jquery will change the html in the selected div. How dos this not answer the question?

Comment: @merski007 I think the issue is that your code removes the the html `<span>` elements from the div, which the OP didn't want to have happen.